# unable to capture mobile app traffic in burp suit

Tags: genymotion, burp

I am trying to intercept the mobile applications traffic using burp. To intercept mobile application traffic i have installed burp suit and genymotion in my pc. I have created Samsung galaxy note 2 device in genymotion and configured the mobile proxy to my burp suit and also i have installed the CA certificate (VPN and apps) as well. while i browse the internet through mobile browser requests are captured in the burp but when i open the Instagram or any other app it is not capturing in the burp. it is showing error.
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYjIZ.png)

can anyone help me to solve this problem. how can i capture the apps traffic?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot intercept or capture the requests from a mobile application until the application's SSL pinning is disabled.

It would help if you had an SSL pinning disabled application or should bypass SSL pinning.

Please refer to this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/151098) and post, and this might be helpful for you.